# MySQL Syntax Error while creating a table - Java

Tags: java, mysql

I have never used mysql before so this is my first attempt. The syntax/coding im using...

```
"CREATE pets (" 
                + "uuid INT NOT NULL,"  
                + "type VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL," 
                + "name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,"  
                + "health INT NOT NULL,"
                + "badge VARCHAR(40),"
                + ")"
```

And the error is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'pets (uuid INT NOT NULL,type VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,he' at line 1

Comment: CREATE _TABLE_ pets...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `table` to the first line

```
"CREATE table pets ("
```

Remove the comma at the end of this line

```
+ "badge VARCHAR(40),"
                    ^------here
```

Generally if you look at the error message you see the first problematic point right after *for the right syntax to use near*

Comment: I removed it and still getting the same error. I want a table with uuid as the int id and then type, name and badge as a string and health as a int @juergen-d EDIT: Didn't have table let me try that